# serverless deployment fails on checking stack progress AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

**Problem:**

I have two lambda functions on AWS representing two different environments (staging and production). The production environment has a data import function which runs every 10 mins. The problem I am facing is that when I try to deploy staging environment, error occurs on the stack update progress as shown:

```
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
.........................
Serverless: Operation failed!

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  An error occurred: MyimportfunctionEventsRuleSchedule1 - schedule-full-import already exists in stack Cloudformation_StackId_of_production_lambda_function.
```

**EDIT**:
schedule-full-import function is for only production environment, not the staging environment. My understanding is that when I try to deploy, it just tries to find the trigger for the staging environment. In this case, it does not find it and then goes towards the production environment.

serverless.yml

```
schedule_full_import:
    handler: my_handler
    timeout: 6
    events:
      - schedule:
          enabled: true
          name: full-data-import
          rate: rate(10 minutes)
          stageParams:
            stage: prod
```

I dont want to trigger this function for the staging environment since it is not needed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your existing CloudFormation stack manually if `$ sls remove` didn't work.

And then redeploy your stack from the scratch.
Of course, make sure you deleted .serverless directory before new deployment.

Comment: The thing is that Data import for production function does not exist in my CloudFormation stack for staging. My understanding is that it is translated from the serverless.yml file where I have the function with the staging params for only production environment which should be the case. Since i don't want data import to run for staging.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that **stageParams** doesn't do what you think it does. It does not attach the lambda to the Cloudwatch trigger only in the prod stage. The Serverless docs (https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/) has a confusing example that lists `stageParams` as an input value to the trigger. All that means is that Cloudwatch will invoke the lambda with the value of `input` as the event data.

There isn't a way to selectively not deploy resources listed in `serverless.yml` depending on the stage. What you could do is set `enabled` to false when stage isn't prod by using some custom configuration parameters. This would deploy the trigger to your staging environment, but it would not be invoked.

The CloudFormation error also suggests there is a naming conflict. Serverless should be generating unique lambda names based on the stage, so if I had to guess the schedule name `full-data-import` isn't unique. I would try renaming it to something like

```
name: full-data-import-${self:provider.stage}
```

Depending on how you reference your stage parameter.

You could try something like:

```
custom:
    importEnabled: <set this by config file, command line argument, environment variable, etc>

functions:
    schedule_full_import:
        handler: my_handler
        timeout: 6
        events:
            - schedule:
                  name: full-data-import-${self:provider.stage}
                  enabled: ${self:custom.importEnabled}
                  rate: rate(10 minutes)
```

See https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/ for ways you could set value of importEnabled

Comment: can you provide configuration example with enabled being set to false which could illustrate the solution.